# Display birthday data of more than 1 person in modal

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm trying to make a modal that popups up when a person's birthday is today. So far the code below works. But now I want to display multiple modal if there are multiple person having the same birthday today. New in Vue. Thanks

**Template**

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="birthdayModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content mx-auto text-center bg-danger text-warning">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>
          HAPPY
          <i class="fa-fw fas fa-birthday-cake"></i> BIRTHDAY!
        </h1>
        <img
          :src="'/img/members/' +birthday.image_name"
          width="250px"
          height="250px"
          class="img img-responsive"
        />
        <h3 class="mt-3">{{birthday.alias_name}}</h3>
        <h3>{{birthday.dob | dateFormatText}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      birthday: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    birthdayModal() {
      axios.get('api/members/birthday').then(res => this.parseAndDisplay(res))
    },
    parseAndDisplay(result) {
      this.birthday = result.data[0]
      if (this.birthday != null) {
        $('#birthdayModal').modal('show')
        console.log('Birthday Data: ', this.birthday)
      } else {
        console.log('Nobody Birthday')
      }
    },
  },
  created() {},
  mounted() {
    this.birthdayModal()
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function birthday()
{   
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $member = Member::whereMonth('dob', '=', $date->month)->whereDay('dob', '=', $date->day)->get();
    return $member;
}
```

[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InhtL.png)

[Network Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOOLq.png)

Comment: please do not include images unless they are really mandatory

Answer (score 0):

I think this steps will help you to solve your problem:

1. If you want to show multiple person's birthday, then you need the information of all persons. Create an array of persons like birthday. `person:[]`
2. Create a for loop on modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"  id="birthdayModal" role="dialog" v-for"person in persons">
   ------
</div>
```

3. If there is a birthday of a person then fire it.

Comment: I tried using v for loop but it doesnt work. I think theres something wrong with the axios response data. Try checking the console n network image i given above. Seems different

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```js
this.birthday = result.data[0]
```

With this, you are always getting only one person's data. Put your all persons data in a variable, like `this.persons = result.data`. Then use `v-for` to loop through them.